What amount of time is between submitting a post to review queue and until the post is getting reviewed?
Is there a rule for posts that are in repeated review for how much time is between editing and submitting for review and a review being started?
Is there a defined wait time until a review can be started?

There's no 'minimum' wait time but reviews are generally best effort, and well, people need to find value in doing them. On some sites, specifically stack overflow the backlog is massive. On other sites, they're just quiet and people don't get into/fall out of the habit of checking the queues.
There's no real 'defined wait time' but if a post is constantly getting into review, there may be other factors (I don't remember for example if a reviewer will get the same post for a different edit, and if not, this can cut into the number of eligible reviewers. Its probably also a VERY good idea to do any fixes you need at once if you can.

i see, if 'opinion based' is the reasoning for 4 reviews ('Original close reason(s) were not resolved'), but meanwhile half of the question was rewritten almost completely, could there be a difficulty on the review queue side? With requesting a closer reasoning in comments i got a reply in the comments with review for the 5th time, that the title was the difficulty to parse. That's now ~5 days. As far i experienced that, edits for the same posting are processed from same reviewers repeatedly. (thx)

Thats, kinda ironically one of the more subjective things. After multiple reviews though - its entirely plausible that well, its pretty much not a good fit, and not really salvagable

"...As far i experienced that, edits for the same posting are processed from same reviewers repeatedly...", depending on the site where the post was made, the number of people willing to give up part of their days to analyze the publications sent to the review queues is low; which creates this perception of the same people analyzing and re-analyzing the posts.
